# How to show someone came from a link on my website?

Tags: referrer, visitor-pattern

It must be the full url, not just history or type. I have seen, on statcounter.com, where they show stats regarding where the referrer of our site came from. I want to show the exact link like statcounter shows under a tab.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your question should amongst others include what language/technologies (PHP, Javascript, ...) you are going to use.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/features/).

Google will generate a unique javascript code for you, you then paste it in your html, which activates the service. It's very easy to get started and the dashboard is very robust considering it's free. To get started, you can check this out: http://www.google.com/analytics/learn/setupchecklist.html

[image]

Comment: I want to show came from link to the visitor where only he is coming from. If another visitor come to my site he will see only the url from which he is coming to my site.

Comment: Ah I understand, please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151647/how-do-i-get-the-referring-site-a-user-came-from-to-arive-on-my-site-using-php?rq=1